# Orderby menu_order not working; menu is sorted on publish date

Tags: menus, order, children, menu-order

I have made a menu in the admin page ordered like this:

```
parent
    - child 1
    - child 2
    - child 3
parent
    - child 1
    - child 2
    - child 3
parent
    - child 1
    - child 2
    - child 3
```

When I load them in my navbar with the following code it works just fine:

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => 'menu-1',
    'menu_id'        => 'primary-menu',
    'menu_class'     => 'top-menu',
    ) );
```

However, I want to load a specific menu on a page based on it's parent. I have done this as followed:

```
<?php 
$children = get_posts( array( 'post_parent' => $parent, 'post_type' => 'page', 'numberposts' => 9, 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC')); 
?>
```

But when it is displayed it displays the menu according to their publishing date:

```
- child 2
- child 1
- child 3
```

I know I can just change the publishing date but this may conflict in the future.

> How do I order these children the same way as I have in the navbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`menu_order` doesn't mean the order in which it is used in any given custom menu. It means order by the "Order" attribute as entered in this box:

[image]

Counterintuitively this attribute is saved into the `menu_order` column in the `wp_posts` table in the database, which is why the `orderby` argument value is `menu_order`.

I'm not certain as I wasn't using WordPress at the time, but I believe this is a holdover from a time when WordPress did not have customisable menus and the only way to output a menu of pages was the `wp_list_pages()` function, which was introduced in `1.5.0` (`wp_nav_menu()` wasn't introduced until `3.0.0`). When that was the way of doing menus ordering menu items was done with this attribute.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, thank you! I really want to avoid ordering them by entering an order number. Is there a way to order it exactly as the menu structure?

Comment: No, not really. There are plugins available that let you order pages with drag and drop, if that makes it easier.